# Normalized data model - looking up simple joins in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have the following data model

```
`Table: Workflow
Field: workflow_id
Field: workflow_name
Field: workflow_step_id`

`Table: Workflow_Step
Field: workflow_step_id
Field: workflow_step_name
Field: workflow_id`

`Table: Workflow_Step_Detail
Field: workflow_step_detail_id
Field: workflow_step_detail_name
Field: country_id
Field: state_id
Field: workflow_step_id`
```

In the controller class

```
`<?php 
 $this->set('workflow', $this->Workflow->findByWorkflowId(1)); // this works fine
?>`
```

In the view file

```
`<?php 
$steps = $workflow['Workflow']['WorkflowStep']; //this gets all the steps
$detail = $steps[0]['WorkflowStepDetail']; // this also works fine
echo $detail['state_id']; //this also works fine
echo $detail['state_name']; // this is what i want 
?>`
```

As you can see from above, this is a highly normalized data model. My CakePHP data structure works fine with `hasMany` and `belongsTo` - it loads all the recursive data structures fine when I do `findByWorkflowId($id)`. However, when I want to display WorkflowStepDetails - i dont want to display just the `country_id` or `state_id` - I would like to display the corresponding name from the `country` and `state` lookup tables. I am unable to figure out how to make this join inherent within the CakePHP `findBy` structure

Comment: Why not use the value you have and perform another `find` on the state lookup table?

Comment: yes - i could do that. but was hoping a more efficient method may exist. Worst case - i will write a custom SQL query and return the resultset back to the view

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to 'rebind' the models temporarily. It's a bit of a hack but all there is until version 3.x:

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations

Comment: I tried this but perhaps I didnt quite understand what you meant. Could you please elaborate a bit. Essentially, I would like to look up the Workflow object (the top of the tree) in the controller and have CakePHP look up recursively all associated elements - including lookup values such as State, Country etc from related tables